# Model.update with Mongoose and $push overwrites the whole array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a very simple database in MongoDB, and part of it consists in Users and Games. Something like this:

```
const GameSchema = new Schema({
  mode: Number
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  games: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'game'
  }]
});
```

So now when I create a game I want to also update the users in the game adding the _id. For example, if I create a game with _id 778, and this game is played by users with _ids 111 and 222, then those users will have their games property updated to add 778.

In a given time the same user could be playing different games, so the user games would evolve, games: [778] => [778,889] => [778,889,901] and so on...

To do that I'm using Mongoose middleware.

```
GameSchema.post('save', function(doc, next) {
  const User = mongoose.model('user');

  Game.findById(doc._id)
    .populate('players')
    .then(game => {
      let userIds = // retrieve the ids of the users playing the game

      if (userIds.length) {
        User.update(
            { _id: { $in: userIds } },
            { $push: { games: this._id } },
            { safe: true, multi: true }
          )
          .then((data) => {
            console.log('updated users', data);
            // here it says that both users were updated
            next();
          });
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
});
```

The thing is, the games can have 2 players or 1 player, and in this last case this works fine, but when there are 2 users to update, instead of updating games to add the new values, it basically overwrites the whole array so it goes [778] => [889] => [901].

Can anyone help me or give me a hint on what could I check to know what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what was happening, it was my mistake.

This was being updated properly in the database but as the User.update is in the middleware I was not returning the updated records and so my Objects in my web app were not being updated.

So when a new game was created for doubles I edited the users to add some control information and hence was overwriting the games values.

Apologies for the question, silly mistake.